# Tokenizing User Input Bug

Tags: c++

I am trying to tokenize user input, and I almost have it, but there is a bug that I can't quite figure out.

```
  char buffer[50];

  fgets(buffer, 50, stdin);

  char *temp = strtok(buffer, " ");
  int argCount = 0;
  while(temp != NULL) {
      cout << temp << endl;
      argCount++;
      temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }//while
```

Spaces I will represent with '_'.

If I were to type "1_2_3_4" argCount returns 4.
If I were to type "1___2__3___4" argCount returns 4.
BUT if I were to type "1_2_3_4___" argCount returns 5.

I expect the output to be 4 like the other examples, however it is not.

Comment: This is tagged "C++", but the code you are showing is very much *C* (except for `cout`). Why don't you take advantage of C++ facilities?

Comment: Don't mix C and C++ code.  And strtok has no place in either.

Comment: My apologies, long day.

Comment: This is not C code.

Comment: I am confused I have people telling me it is either C or C++. All semester I've been coding in C++.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: https://ideone.com/XQGBKB

Comment: JesperJuhl said that the code doesn't take advantage of C++ features, which is true. Except for `cout << ...` it is also valid C. But the use of `cout` means it isn't C.

Comment: There are a lot of things you can do in C++ that you really shouldn't.  If you use functions like `malloc` , `fgets`, `printf`, and many more, your code looks like C.

Comment: tokenizing on space in c++ will typically look something like `std::string token; while (std::cin >> token) { std::cout << token << std::endl; }` Much simpler, no?

Comment: _ must be the token howcum you are getting count!!!

Comment: If you step through the loop with the [debugging tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that should have come with your development environment you should get a good look at what has gone wrong. Debuggers are one of the programmer's best weapons against unruly code.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ah I see, thank you for clearing up the confusion, I am still relatively new to this C/C++ stuff.

Comment: @melpomene Ah ok, thanks a lot for clearing up the confusion I have learned a lot.

Comment: @melpomene That's weird, I'm running mine on Emacs on a server that my school uses for our assignments so perhaps that has something to do with it?

Comment: Nothing to do with EMACS. Colleges and universities have an annoying tendency to teach C and tell you it's C++. C and C++ have a lot of similarities due to C++ deriving from the C of a much earlier time, but both languages, in particular the ideologies driving the languages and their uses, have diverged greatly. Sometimes the curriculum dates back a decade or two to when the languages were more similar and the instructors are tied to this legacy thinking and infrastructure and sometimes the instructors don't actually know C++ nearly as well as they think they do.

Comment: Suggestion: Get a full-featured IDE with at least a built-in debugger (and profiling tools if you can get them) and install it on your PC. Toy around with a couple of them to find out what tools you like best. Do most of your homework the easy way with tools that suit you. When you have the program beaten into submission on your system, finish it off on the school server. Usually this will save you a lot of time.

Comment: [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/5eA6Ye)